# Checkinstall failed with /root/rpmbuild has no source directory

Tags: linux, checkinstall

I am trying to use `checkinstall` to build a package from source code. 
However, when I run checkinstall , it ask :

> /root/rpmbuild has no source directory, please write the path to the
>   rpm source directory tree.

I am running on Fedora 12 and system was installed through kickstart via repository of dvd of fc12. I was not aware of the rpm source directory during the installation.

So how can I check whether rpm source has been installed or not? If not, how to make the rpm source directory so that I can please the checkinstall and build the package successfully? Or can I bypass it?

Answer (score 10):

Install the `rpmdevtools` package:

```
Name       : rpmdevtools
Arch       : noarch
Version    : 7.5
Release    : 1.el6
Size       : 216 k
Repo       : installed
From repo  : base
Summary    : RPM Development Tools
URL        : https://fedorahosted.org/rpmdevtools/
License    : GPLv2+ and GPLv2
Description: This package contains scripts and (X)Emacs support files to aid in
           : development of RPM packages.
           : rpmdev-setuptree    Create RPM build tree within user's home directory
           : rpmdev-diff         Diff contents of two archives
           : rpmdev-newspec      Creates new .spec from template
           : rpmdev-rmdevelrpms  Find (and optionally remove) "development" RPMs
           : rpmdev-checksig     Check package signatures using alternate RPM keyring
           : rpminfo             Print information about executables and libraries
           : rpmdev-md5/sha*     Display checksums of all files in an archive file
           : rpmdev-vercmp       RPM version comparison checker
           : spectool            Expand and download sources and patches in specfiles
           : rpmdev-wipetree     Erase all files within dirs created by rpmdev-setuptree
           : rpmdev-extract      Extract various archives, "tar xvf" style
           : rpmdev-bumpspec     Bump revision in specfile
           : ...and many more.
```

and run `rpmdev-setuptree` to create the directory structure:

```
# tree -L 1 rpmbuild/
rpmbuild/
├── BUILD
├── RPMS
├── SOURCES
├── SPECS
└── SRPMS
```

Answer (score 2):

the solution you seek is:

(as root) mkdir -p /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES

Comment: It was indeed...